# Issue with model being passed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

***Update*** I was pointing to the incorrect view in the controller.

Not sure what i'm missing but my item being passed is what the view want's for a model. When Clicking Delete to remove an entry.

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type PAL.Intranet.Models.FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured, but this dictionary requires a model item of type System.Collections.Geeric.IEnumerable1[PAL.Intranet.Models.FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured]`

Insured

```
@model IEnumerable<PAL.Intranet.Models.FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CCGN Insured Fee Schedule";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/Content/CSS/MetroButtonWidth.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2>CCGN Insured Fee Schedule</h2>
<hr class="bg-dark" />

@if (User.IsInRole("Intranet Admins"))
{
    <p>
        <button class="button small-button info buttonWidth100" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CCGNInsuredCreate", "FeeSchedule")'">Create New</button>
        <br />  
    </p>
}

<table class="table hovered bordered striped border">
    <tr>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            CPT
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            Description
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            Insured Office Fee
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            10% Coin
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            20% Coin
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            30% Coin
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            Insured Non Office Fee
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            10% Coin
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            20% Coin
        </th>
        <th class="fg-white bg-dark">
            30% Coin
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CPT)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsuredOfficeFee)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IOF10)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IOF20)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IOF30)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsuredNonOfficeFee)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.INOF10)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.INOF20)
        </td>
        <td class="text-small">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.INOF30)
        </td>

        @if (User.IsInRole("Intranet Admins"))
        {
            <td>
                <button class="button small-button info buttonWidth75" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CCGNInsuredEdit", "FeeSchedule", new { id = item.ID })'">Edit</button>
                <button class="button small-button danger buttonWidth75" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CCGNInsuredDelete", "FeeSchedule", new { id = item.ID })'">Delete</button>
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}

</table>


<button class="button small-button danger buttonWidth75" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CCGNInsuredDelete", "FeeSchedule", new { id = item.ID })'">Delete</button>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult CCGNInsuredDelete(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured = db.FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured.Find(id);
        if (FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View("/Views/FeeSchedule/CCGN/InsuredIndex.cshtml", FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured);
    }
```

Delete View

```
@model PAL.Intranet.Models.FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured
```

Comment: share your InsuredIndex view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a single object of `FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured` to your view `InsuredIndex.cshtml` which must contain the following definition:

```
@model IEnumerable<PAL.Intranet.Models.FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured>
```

(or a collection derived from `IEnumerable`)

Either change your `FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured` view to use a single instance of `FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured` or update your return to forward it to the delete view you mention:

```
return View("/Views/FeeSchedule/CCGN/delete.cshtml", FeeSchedule_CCGNInsured);
```

Comment: @Tsukasa No probs, only know because I've been there many times. :)